# How do I sort a Set to a List

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, set

In Android, I have a `Set`, and I want to turn it into a sorted `List`.

How to do it with `Collections.sort()`?

```
protected List<PackageInfo> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Set<PackageInfo> adPackages = new HashSet<PackageInfo>();
        //ArrayList<PackageInfo> adPackages = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        [..............]

        return new ArrayList<PackageInfo>(adPackages);
        //return adPackages;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List has a constructor which allows you to create it using any Collection. Then use the Collections.sort(List list) method.

E.g.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("This is a unsorted set");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
Collections.sort(list); // or Collections.sort(list, Comparator);
```

Cheers.

Comment: If you're going to suggest populating a list with another data structure, why not inform OP of *sorted* data structures instead?

Comment: Because others have already stated that method.. i'm just giving a different option. There could be a case where the OP is restricted to a sorted List (though i can't imagine why), but my answer is simply giving another choice. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an Android question. Look for `java sort, comparator`. Here is a nice tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, I would use a [`SortedSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/SortedSet.html) instead of the standard `Set`, and then use the [`addAll`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20E%3E%29) method of the `List` interface to convert the set (that is implicitly sorted) into a sorted list without having to do any sorting outside of the data structures.

Note that this will require that the objects stored within these data structures implement the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you

```
public void sortArrayPackage(ArrayList<PackageInfo> array)
{
  Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<PackageInfo>(){
    public int compare(PackageInfo o1, PackageInfo o2) {
      System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");
      String package1 = o1.packageName;
      String package2 = o2.packageName;

      return package1.compareTo(package2);
    }
  });
}
```